# Why the size of this math expression is not increasing?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, fontsize, math-fonts

It seems I'm missing something here. **Question**: Why the font size of the second math expression below is not increasing - and how can we make it display in larger font? It's displaying both the first and second math expressions of the same size. I thought the second one would be much bigger in size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\sum_{k=0}^n \]
\par
\[{\Huge\sum_{k=0}^n} \]
\par
{\Huge This is a test\par}
\end{document}
```

**Display in TeXWorks of MikTeX on my Windows 10**:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

For some reasons, my `TeXworks` editor is not showing the `.log` file. My [online search](https://www.google.com/search?q=texworks%20not%20showing%20log%20file&ei=0ZyDYKjmEYy8tAb2g4_oCw&oq=texworks%20not%20showing%20log%20file&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAxQAFgAYOs7aABwAngAgAEtiAEtkgEBMZgBAKoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjokuL8g5bwAhUMHs0KHfbBA70Q4dUDCA4) shows many other users facing the same issue. But when I ran `pdflatex MyTexFile` on `DOS prompt` (or `powershell` prompt) I see the `.log` file got generated - and it showed a warning: `LaTeX Font Warning: Command \Huge invalid in math mode on input`. So I tried the following and it worked. But I would like to see better alternatives (if there are any). I'm glad user `@Werner` suggested me to look for log file (as it gave me a clue):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\sum_{k=0}^n \]
\par
\[{\Huge\sum_{k=0}^n } \]\par
\[ \mbox{\Huge $\sum_{k=0}^n$ } \]
\par
\[ \mbox{\Huge $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n$ } \]
\par
{\Huge This is a test\par}
\end{document}
```

**TeXworks display in MikTeX**:

[image]

**Remark** You may also refer to the suggestions from `@werner` and `@DavidCarlisle` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594221/why-the-size-of-this-math-expression-is-not-increasing#comment1490562_594221) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594221/why-the-size-of-this-math-expression-is-not-increasing#comment1490594_594221) - and some good responses below from other users  for better alternatives.

Comment: `\Huge` is a declaration for text mode, not for math mode

Comment: What do you see in your `.log` when you compile your example? Is there a warning about fonts?

Comment: @Werner I am not seeing the `.log` file. After reading your comment, I created a new folder just for this `.tex` file so after compilation I could see all the files the compilation generates. And I see only following three files generated: `MyTexFile.tex`, `MyTexFile.pdf`, and `MyTexFile.synctex.gz`. Where could the `.log` file be? Is there any TeXWorks settings that I need to configure to get the log file. There are no errors or warnings during compilation.

Comment: My guess would be that your operating system (Windows?) is not showing you the log file.  Try looking for an option to show hidden files.

Comment: @Teepeemm I see someone else having the same .log file issue posted [here](https://tug.org/pipermail/texworks/2018q3/006820.html). Let me try to find it out.

Comment: If you are using MikTeX, to see the log file, in your TeXworks editor, go to Edit, Preferences, Typesetting tab, then select the compile option you are using, for example, pdflatex, and click Edit.  You will see a list of compiler syntax used to invoke a compilation run.  There is an option `--clean` that removes extra files automatically, such as the log file.  You have to eliminate this `--clean` option if you want the compilation to leave your log file in place.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm using MikTeX. In TeXworks editor, when I select the compile option `pdflatex`, I get only the following entries in the `Arguments` section: `$synctexoption`, `-undump=pdflatex`, `$fullname`. Should anything out of these options be removed?

Comment: @nam: You can also `\usepackage{graphicx}` ... `\[ \scalebox{3}{$\displaystyle <math>$} \]`; `\scalebox{<num>}{<stuff>}` considers its argument as text, so use `$`...`$` around `<stuff>` if it should be math, scaling it with a factor of `<num>`.

Comment: just move the `\Huge` before the `\[` there is no need to have \ nested mbox here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\Huge\[\sum_{k=0}^n \]` worked. That was simple.

Comment: @Werner Your suggestion worked. I had to install another package since MikTeX gave the message: `tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty is missing that is a part of epstopdf-pkg`. But I noticed that using `\scalebox{<num>}{<stuff>}` I can also do scaling based on my needs.

Comment: @nam -- scaling is *not* the best way to address this.  Matching the size of `\Huge` by that method is not straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

The simplistic suggestion of moving `\Huge` in front of `\[` is not good, I'm afraid.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{xdisplaymath}[1][\huge]
 {\[\begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}#1\[}
 {\]\end{minipage}\]\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2][1-4]
\[\sum_{k=0}^n \]
\lipsum[2][1-5]
\begin{xdisplaymath}
\sum_{k=0}^n
\end{xdisplaymath}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not going to improve this to allow for equation numbers, as I can't see any usefulness in this typographic horror. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

My simple suggestion it is to use `scalerel` package to increase or to decrease the size of the sum (for example), as alternative to `\Huge` not correct in math-mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
This is a sum inline mode, with a text before
$\scaleto{\sum_{k=0}^n}{50pt}$ and after. If you prefer to have in math-mode:
\[\scaleto{\sum_{k=0}^n}{100pt}, \quad \scaleto{\sum_{k=0}^n}{50pt}, \quad \sum_{k=0}^n, \quad \scaleto{\sum_{k=0}^n}{20pt}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]